# function showToast is deleting the element instead of outputting a message

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins

//the function show toast supposed to check if the element is empty without deleting the element itself
//if it's empty it outputs EMPTY
//if it's not it outputs NOT EMPTY

```
 function showToast(){
if(document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML= ""){
    window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
        {
        message: "NOT EMPTY",
        duration: "short",
        position: "bottom",
        },
    );
    }else{
        window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
           {
            message: "EMPTY",
            duration: "short",
            position: "bottom",
            },
        );
    }
```

}

Comment: use == instead of = in if condition

Comment: thankyou it worked

Comment: You're welcome :)